# Using a proxy server vs. Local main IP

Tags: proxy, ip, ip-address

Let's say I have a squid proxy server with 10 IPs assigned to it (locally on my gigE network).

And let's also say I have a different server with a different 10 IPs assigned to it, running a c# application which is running 10 threads, each thread being used to crawl a website.  Each thread using a different assigned IP to send out its HTTP request.

My question is, if I run 10 threads in that application where each thread uses a proxy IP from the proxy server to crawl the website.  And I also try 10 threads in that app where each thread uses a locally assigned IP directly on the server to crawl the site.  Which will go faster to crawl the site from page to page, a thread using a proxy IP, or a thread using a direct IP from its own server?

I would imagine a direct IP on the server because proxy servers have inherent latencies but its proving to show the proxy server is being slightly faster.  So I'm confused.  Maybe its because using a direct IP uses some processing power and by using a proxy server it is able to outsource that processing to the proxy server?  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: We need to see your crawling code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that 10 different threads "crawl the site", which sounds like you have 10 threads scraping different pages of the same site.

In this case, using a proxy is often faster.  Remember that most html pages look something like this:

```
foo1.html
  |
  +--- Link: somefile01.xml
  |
  +--- Link: somestlyesheet.css
  |
  +--- Image: somepicture01.jpg
  |
  +--- Image: somepicture02.jpg

foo2.html
  |
  +--- Link: somefile01.xml
  |
  +--- Link: somestlyesheet.css
  |
  +--- Image: somepicture01.jpg
  |
  +--- Image: somepicture03.jpg
```

After a real web brower pulls `foo1.html`, it performs http GETs for `somefile01.xml`, `somestylesheet.css`, `somepicture01.jpg`, and `somepicture02.jpg` (usually in parallel). Presumably, if you scrape pages from the same site, you're scraping pages that have some common overlap in content (such as shown above between `foo1.html` and `foo2.html`).

If you have http object caching enabled on your proxy, your threads will be faster because you will get cache hits for some fraction of those files.  If there is a cache hit, then the file is delivered to your code locally from the Squid cache on your LAN, instead of having to source it from the remote server every time.

If you have 10 threads which all crawl different sites, then you should expect slower performance unless the only file they included was something like `jquery.js`.  Incidentally, google offers web developers a way to use their cache to load several commmon javascript files.

Comment: This only holds when caching is actually enabled, and the same file is accessed more than once (e.g. linked resources). By now, most proxies do not seem to do any caching anymore. Plus, it didn't seem as if the original poster actually accessed linked resources.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) [caches http objects by default](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache/).  The point above is that *most* html in the real world includes links to a `.css` file or images, because web pages on the same site are templated to look like each other.

Comment: *Most* crawlers will however not follow links to `.css` files or visit the same page more than once.

Comment: That was EXTREMELY helpful, thank you.  Actually, all 10 threads do the exact same site at the exact same time, in the same order.  So caching would be helpful.  I just thought that proxy servers are inherently slower as you are going through a proxy instead of directly doing it from the application server.  However I am seeing neither faster nor slower results.  Is http object caching something that I will have to configure within squid?

Comment: @BarryHarris, [Squid http object caching is enabled by default](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache/).  However, I'm not sure I understand your last statement about proxy / no-proxy response time.  The question said a proxy is slightly faster, but the last comment said the proxy is neither faster nor slower.   Finally, if this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check box underneath my answer score.

Comment: Sorry if that's unclear.  The two are extremely close in speed, but proxy is a tiny bit faster.  I said neither faster nor slower because the time is pretty insignificant.  The application, if running 10 threads, each thread visits the same site and does the same exact thing each time.  It does not load images, just the page content.